# table scrollbar does not work in IE

Tags: css, html

I'm creating simple html table with scrollbar, issue is in IE scrollbar is not visible and table is expanding to full height. Please find
the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7t9qkLc0/53/, it works in FF and chrome but not in IE. Please suggest what changes to be done to see scrollbar inside table in IE.
Below is sample code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" height="100px">
     <tr>
     <td colspan="3"  style="vertical-align: top;">
        <table class="myTable" border="1" height="95px">
        <tr><th><B>Column1 </B></th></tr>
    <tr> 
        <td> Data1
    </td></tr>

  <tr> 
    <td> Data2
    </td></tr>

<tr> 
    <td> Data3
    </td></tr>
 <tr> 
    <td> Data4
     </td></tr>

<tr> 
        <td> Data5
     </td></tr>

<tr> 
        <td> Data6
     </td></tr> <tr> 
        <td> Data7
     </td></tr>

<tr> 
        <td> Data8
    </td></tr>

<tr> 
            <td> Data9
    </td></tr>  
<tr> 
        <td> Data10
     </td></tr>

<tr> 
    <td> Data11
        </td></tr>

<tr> 
        <td> Data12
        </td></tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using tables within tables, which isn't necessary and isn't good practice. Instead, put your table in a parent container with a fixed height, and set that to scroll.

```
<div class="tableHolder">
    <table class="myTable">
        <!-- table code -->
    </table>
</div>

.tableHolder {
    height: 95px;
    overflow-y: scroll;   
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px inset #000;
}
.myTable th, .myTable td{
    border: 1px inset #000;
}
```

Here's a revised fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ey6x6549/